# Getting erroneous results while running inference with quantized TFlite weights

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, fpga

I want to export a quantized model onto FPGA

I adopted the Quantization Aware Training flow as per https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_example to get a tflite model with uint8 quantization.

Dataset :MNIST

Model used:

```
  model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28, 28)),   
  keras.layers.Flatten(),                    
  keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

Accuracy Results of tflite model obtained

```
Quant TFLite test_accuracy: 0.9478
Quant TF test accuracy: 0.9527000188827515
```

Now, I want to use this quantized model on FPGA. So, I export the tflite model and export the weights as numpy array using netron (https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) .

Using these weights, I run an inference on python by handcoding the forward path as shown . I get accuracy = 32 % as against the accuarcy of 95% obtained using tflite interpreter .

Here is the handcoded forward path

```
w_32x784=np.load("w_32x784.npy")
b_32 = np.load("b_32.npy")
w_16x32 = np.load("w_16x32.npy")
b_16 = np.load("b_16.npy")
w_10x16 = np.load("w_10x16.npy")
b_10 =np.load("b_10.npy")

def eval_q(x_inp):
    layer1_op = relu(np.squeeze(np.matmul(w_32x784,x_inp))+b_32)
    layer2_op = relu(np.squeeze(np.matmul(w_16x32,layer1_op))+b_16)
    layer3_op = np.squeeze(np.matmul(w_10x16,layer2_op))+b_10
    predict = np.argmax(layer3_op)
    return predict

def relu(w):
    op =[x if x > 0 else 0 for x in w]
    return op 

# Evaluate Model
predictions=[]
for img in test_images:
    x_inp = img.reshape(784,1)
    predictions.append(eval_q(x_inp))
print((predictions==test_labels).mean())
```

```
Accuracy =0.3248
```

Please help me out with finding where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Can you compare the prediction from keras model and tflite model on the same images? Did you check whether you get same prediction?

Comment: Yeah. Most of the values match between keras and tftlite models. Like I showed accuracy is around 95%

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check how quantization works in TensorFlow - maybe you missed handling zero-point and scale?

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.05877.pdf
- https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/quantization_spec

Comment: That's true. After including the scale factors, i'm able to reproduce accuracy of 95% using the code in the question (which is the same as that obtained using quantization flow using keras)